# Java connection to oracle database takes forever

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have been writing a java application using oracle database.
Originally, my connection url was

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

It has been working perfectly. I wanted to change my url so that I can connect to my database from any laptops.
I changed my connection url to

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-3ME2EPSM)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
```

which is the format I found on the Internet. After changing my connection url, I cannot connect to my database anymore. There's no errors. The program just keeps running forever and the connection never finishes.

Below is my listener.ora:

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = some local address)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:some local address")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-3ME2EPSM)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

This is my tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-3ME2EPSM)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-3ME2EPSM)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-3ME2EPSM)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Connection String looks ok to me... Could you try putting `localhost` instead of  `LAPTOP-3ME2EPSM` in the connection url and see if the behaviour changes?

Comment: @Plirkee, I have already tried that. The behavior does not change. There's still no errors. The connection takes forever and never completes

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are able to connect using the URL using SQL Plus? Your database might be a local database.

Comment: How would I connect to the URL using SQL Developer?